# Подключится к MySQL через hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

Моя база данный

```
CREATE TABLE `ggloor`.`teams` (
  `idteam` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idteam`));
```

Настройки в applicatin.yml

```
hibernate:
    cache:
        queries: false
        use_second_level_cache: true
        use_query_cache: false
        region.factory_class: org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory

dataSource:
    pooled: true
    jmxExport: true
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    username: root
    password: 1111

environments:
    development:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ggloor?useSSL=false
    test:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ggloor?autoreconnect=true;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
    production:
        dataSource:
            dbCreate: create-drop
            url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ggloor?autoreconnect=true;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
            properties:
                jmxEnabled: true
                initialSize: 5
                maxActive: 50
                minIdle: 5
                maxIdle: 25
                maxWait: 10000
                maxAge: 600000
                timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis: 5000
                minEvictableIdleTimeMillis: 60000
                validationQuery: SELECT 1
                validationQueryTimeout: 3
                validationInterval: 15000
                testOnBorrow: true
                testWhileIdle: true
                testOnReturn: false
                jdbcInterceptors: ConnectionState
                defaultTransactionIsolation: 2 # TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
```

Создал домен

```
package testgrails12

import grails.persistence.Entity

@Entity
class Teams {
    Integer idteam
    String name
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```

Контроллер

```
package testgrails12

class BdconnectController {

    def index() {
        def team = Teams.get(1)
        team.delete()
        team.save()
        render "hello"
    }
}
```

Получаю ошибку на этапе выполнения

> Error 500: Internal Server Error URI /bdconnect/index Class
>   com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException Message null
>   Caused by Unknown column 'teams0_.id' in 'field list'

Пытался создавать hibernate.cfg.xml, Teams.hbm.xml в папке conf это не дало результатов.

Как все правильно настроить?

Comment: Судя по сообщению, выполняется попытка найти в структуре поле по имени `id`, которого там нет, ибо имя поля - первичного индекса есть `idteam`. Однако нигде в коде Вы не указываете, что первичный индекс именно такой, Вы просто описываете, что такое поле существует. Вот этот момент, вероятно, и надо исправить...

Comment: @Akina я как бы себя не просто так программистом зову, я понимаю суть ошибки, а как исправить не знаю. Конкретно, как задать первичное поле?

Comment: Навскидку так: `@Entity
class Teams {
    @Id
    Integer idteam;
    String name;
}`

Comment: @Akina я пробовал, это не решило проблему

Answer (score 0):

```
package testgrails12

class Teams {
    Integer id
    String name
    static mapping = {
        table 'teams'
        version false
        name column: 'name'
        id column: 'idteam', sqlType: 'INT(11)', updateable: false, insertable: false
    }
    static constraints = {
    }
}
```